# Browsing an ASP.net app from ISS on local machine and getting ERROR

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm having trouble viewing an ASP.net site using the browse function within ISS. When I click browse I'm able to hit the directory page but when selecting the aspx page that I require I'm getting

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

everything looks to be ok and I have looked at numerous pages around the issue I'm having however not all are clear , this is my first time publishing and trying to hit the asp.net app via ISS.

I have added pictures of what I'm up to and seeing, any help will be appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuqki.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czLJ8.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLGKE.png)

Comment: You mixed WebForms and MVC so routing rules can break up navigation.

Comment: is there any where you can point me to reslove this issue ?

Comment: How did you deploy the asp.net project to IIS? I suspect this may be that you did not correctly deploy the asp.net project to IIS.

Comment: Can you solve this problem by adding a new site? Do not deploy the asp.net project to the default site.

Comment: i added this as a new site as recommended and i now can run the asp.net site via IIS, however I'm now getting an error when im trying to insert data into a SQL table , it works fine on test mode but error via the published site. I have read a number of articles and nothing so far has worked , the error im getting doesnt give me a lot of infomation about what is causing the issue ,

Comment: the error is Server Error in '/' Application.
Runtime Error
Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

Comment: Will exceptions occur only when operating on the database? I suspect it may be related to permissions. Can you get specific exception information?